# Yii2-getting type and reference errors in console

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am working on `Yii2`. In my console, I am getting 2 type of errors.

1. > Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
   >   at bootstrap-show-password.min.js:6
   >   at bootstrap-show-password.min.js:6

**Line of error** [bootstrap-show-password](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-show-password/1.0.3/bootstrap-show-password.min.js) at `var i=e.fn.password;e.fn.password=function()......}(window.jQuery);`

2. > Uncaught ReferenceError: $st is not defined
   >   at common.js:263

**Line of error** [common](http://chrome-extension://lgblnfidahcdcjddiepkckcfdhpknnjh/common/common.js) at `if ($st && $stats && blockingRules && setupUser && !window.forceReload)..`

Below is my declaration in `main.php` file

```
<?php $this->beginPage() ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="<?= Yii::$app->language ?>">
<head>
<meta charset="<?= Yii::$app->charset ?>">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<?= Html::csrfMetaTags() ?>
<title><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></title>
<?php $this->head() ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!-- Ionicons -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-show-password/1.0.3/bootstrap-show-password.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini">
<?php $this->beginBody() ?>
```

**Update 1**

Some scripts in my `main.php`

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.listing-img').on('click', function () {
        $('#modal-img-tag').attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
        $('#image-view-modal').modal();
    });
});
</script>
<script>
var data = [];
<?php foreach(\app\models\Roles::toArrayList() as $k=>$v){?>
data.push({id:<?=$k?>, text: '<?=$v?>'});
<?php } ?>
if($(".select2-selection").length>0) {
    $(".select2-selection").select2({
        data: data,
        allowClear: true,
        placeholder: "Select a Role",
        multiple: true
    });
}
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/dist/jspdf.min.js"> 
</script>
<div id="pdf-editor"></div>
</body>
</html>
<?php $this->endPage() ?>
```

I have searched for these both for `yii2/yii` but I couldn't find any suitable solution

How can I get rid of these errors?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know why downvoters didn't tell the reason.

Comment: what i suspect is that you should first of all use the latest [release](https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-show-password/releases) for the extension and include the `v 1.1.2` as of the github link this is the latest one  and you are using `1.0.3`, there is a high probability that these issues vanish if they are related to the extension and not your code.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam I have updated the version to `1.1.2` but still I am facing these errors

Comment: if you comment out the extension `bootstrap-show-password` is the issue resolved with the `common.js` ? and the link you provided for common.js is giving 404

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam by commenting it the `1` issue is resolved but `2` remains

Comment: ok, replace your minified version with [this](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-show-password/1.1.2/bootstrap-show-password.js) link and tell me at which line it raises the error and add the exception here

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam line number `168 var old = $.fn.password;` and line number `217 }(window.jQuery);` with error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
    at bootstrap-show-password.js:168
    at bootstrap-show-password.js:217`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178928/discussion-between-muhammad-omer-aslam-and-mr-faisal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your layout file you are including the `bootstrap-show-password.js` file using the `<script>` tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-show-password/1.0.3/bootstrap-show-password.min.js"></script>
```

and that too inside the `<head>` section whereas by default if you use `AssetManager` or `registerJsFile` it would add the scripts to the bottom of the page before the `</body>` tag, and the `bootstrap-show-password.js` should be loaded after the `jquery` and `bootstrap` js libraries rather than before it,see below sequence on the demo of the [bootstrap-show-password](http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/bootstrap-show-password/v2.html)

```
 <script src="assets/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="assets/bootstrap-v2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
 <script src="bootstrap-show-password.js"></script>
```

That is the reason why you are getting the error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined at
>   bootstrap-show-password.min.js:6 at bootstrap-show-password.min.js:6

your jquery and bootstrap is loading into the bottom of the page rather than head.

You should replace the script tag with

```
$this->registerJsFile('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-show-password/1.1.2/bootstrap-show-password.min.js',[
    'depends'=> \yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset::class
]);
```

so that the file is loaded after the bootstrap and jquery libraries.

And about the other error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $st is not defined at common.js:263

It is related to some extension that is installed in your chrome browser looking at the link you provided it searches the chrome extensions with that name you might try using any other browser like FF or IE as the demo url does not load that specific script for me when using chrome, neither the file `common.js` is included anywhere in the layout or the `AssetManager` files.